# Segfault when accessing a csv file

Tags: segmentation-fault

I found the following piece of code online a while ago as I wanted to extract data from CSV file, which worked just fine until it stopped working. It is now causing a segfault that is driving me crazy as I am not very experienced in C++. I cannot seem to find the source of this segfault. Help pleeeeeeease.

I put the function inside a header file (definition inside the header file as well as it it simple a straightforward)

It is worth mentioning that the code works in another folder, but does not in my current one where I am creating a library and all other header files (classes) are created inside a namespace (not sure if this is related to this though).

This is the header file:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > getData(std::string fileName, std::string delimeter = ",")
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName);
 
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > dataList;

    std::string line = "";

    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        // my investigation led me here: code does not get to this point; it skips the while loop that is why the dataList remains empty

        std::vector<std::string> vec;
        boost::algorithm::split(vec, line, boost::is_any_of(delimeter));
        dataList.push_back(vec);
    }
    file.close();
    
 
    return dataList;
}
```

This is the main

```
int main(){

    int x{7};
    
    Eigen::VectorXd  X_step(x);
    std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> X;

    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > dataList = getData("MyFile.csv");
    std::cout << "data list " << dataList[0][0] << "\n"; // dataList seems to be empty and also cout causes a segfault

    for(std::vector<std::string> vec : dataList)
    {
        int j{0};
        for(std::string data : vec)
        {
            X_step(j) = stod(data);
            j++;
        }
        X.push_back(X_step);
    }
}
```

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, the file was not even being opened.
In order to make sure the file is opened, the csv file must be in the same folder as the executable rather than in the same folder as the main.